# How can I pass this structure into the available functions?

Tags: c++, function, struct

I need help passing a structure through a function to collect and print out its corresponding information. When I try and run the code below the compiler returns that I have too many arguments for the functions.

[image: An image of my full code showing the corresponding errors]

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int num;
void getInput();
void classBank();

struct Record
    {
        string fname, sname;
        int marks, indexNum;
        double average;
    };


int main()
{


    Record student;
    getInput();
    classBank(student);

}


void getInput()
{
    cout<<"How many people are you dealing with: ";
    cin >> num;
}

void classBank(struct student)
{

for(int i = 1; i < num; i++)
    {
       cin >> student[i].fname;
       cin >> student[i].sname;
       cin >> student[i].marks;
       cin >> student[i].indexNum;
       cin >> student[i].average;
    }

}
```

Comment: You've got this function forward-declared with different amount of arguments.

Comment: what is the question? Your compiler is correct, you need to fix the code ;)

Comment: Can you help me out fixing it.. @us

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
void getInput();
void classBank();
```

with

```
void getInput();
void classBank(Record student);
```

**EDIT**:
That code won't work 'cause of several reasons:

1. You declare functions that use struct Record, before declaration of Record
2. You do not understand what keyword `struct` means
3. You pass single element (without overloaded []), not an array to the classBank

**EDIT2** Typo

Comment: @IsaacAttuah ...because `Record` is not known at the point where the forward declarations are placed, move the declaration of `Record` before the forward declarations

Comment: @Thomas Thanks I fixed the problem.. I first repositioned and reworked the structure `struct Record
    {
        string fname[5], sname[5];
        int marks[5], indexNum[5];
        double average[5];
    };`  and did what you told me to do. Thanks again!

Comment: Your edit to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276) was rejected because it's not correct. `justify-items` and `justify-self` do not apply to flexbox. It's even in the [W3C link you provided](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-align-3/#propdef-justify-self): *"Applies to: block-level boxes, absolutely-positioned boxes, and grid items"*. No "flex items".